# Vue.js 1.0 select

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my webapp I've a select like this:

```
<select class="Form-group-item" v-model="user.corporation_id">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Corporatie</option>
    <option v-for="corporation in corporations" v-bind:value="corporation.id">{{ corporation.name }}</option>
</select>
```

So I receive `user.corporation_id` in a json format:

```
corporation_id:2
```

And I set it on the user object. But when I look into my `vue-devtools` `user.corporation_id` is `''` ??

When I remove the entire select from my html

`user.corporation_id = 2` !

What's wrong here??

Comment: What did you imagine putting `selected` would do? That's the selected option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove 'selected' from the default option

```
<select class="Form-group-item" v-model="user.corporation_id">
    <option value="" disabled>Corporatie</option>
    <option v-for="corporation in corporations" v-bind:value="corporation.id">{{ corporation.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Since you have it as 'selected' it's overriding the value you have set and changing it to ''.